# html button to reset field in mysql database using php

Tags: php, mysql

Kinda new to mysql and php

I have a hit counter for each page on my site and a private page that list all pages and hits.
I have a button that will reset all pages to zero and next to each page listing I have a reset button that will reset each page individually. This all was using a text file but now I am swtching to mysql database. I have coded the "RESET ALL" button to work but can not get the individual page buttons to work.

the processing code is:

```
    if($_POST[ind_reset]) {
$ind_reset = $_POST[ind_reset];
mysql_connect("server", "username", "password") or die(mysql_error()); 
 mysql_select_db("database") or die(mysql_error());
    $sql = 'UPDATE counters SET Hits =\'0\' WHERE Page = \'$ind_reset\';';
      }
```

and the html form code is a string:

```
$page_reset = "<form id='Reset' action='counter_update.php' method='post'>
    <button type='submit' name='ind_reset' value='$formPage'>RESET</button>
    </form>";
```

Comment: Please read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) before you create a [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/) so gigantic it ruins your day. You must escape any and all user-supplied values that are put into a query or you will be in trouble.

Comment: ..at first sight this code produces problems like $_POST[ind_reset]. Is "ind_reset" perhaps?

Comment: I read the SQL escaping and changed the code to what you see below. However, I'm not sure I fully understand it!       $stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE counters SET Hits = '0' where Page = \'$ind_reset\'');
  $stmt->bind_param('si',$ind_reset);
  $stmt->execute();

Comment: thanks for the quick response! tadman and vizvi !!   vizvi, why is that a problem?

Comment: Sorry I keep getting interrupted  So I changed code and now gettin internal server error. can't figure out why!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with the first thing:

```
if($_POST[ind_reset]) {
```

should be

```
if($_POST['ind_reset']) {
```

It works without quotes because PHP is silently correcting your error. If you turned error reporting to E_ALL, you would get to see the error message.

One thing that you need to consider is that you can never trust POST data to be what you think it's supposed to be.  Maybe you put in a typo.  Maybe a hacker is sending you fake POST data.  Whichever it is, it will mess up your code if the wrong thing gets put in that database update.  For this reason, instead of simply plugging in that POST value into your database, you should have a checker to make sure that the value is a valid one.  When I do things like this, I make an array of possible values and use only those values when updating or inserting into the database.  Example:

```
$pages = array('value_on_page'=>'value_put_in_database', 
               'xyz'=>'thing_in_database_2');
//the valid things to post are either 'value_on_page' or 'xyz',
//but what goes into the database are the values those keys point to
//e.g. if $_POST['ind_reset'] == 'xyz', $ind_reset will be 'thing_in_database_2'

$key = $_POST['ind_reset'];
if(!isset($pages[$key])) {  
    //if that posted value isn't a key in the array, it's bad
    error_log('Invalid posted page'.$key);
} else {
    //this is a valid posted page
    $ind_reset = $pages[$key]; 

    //** do the database stuff right here in this spot **//
}
```

Now, for the reason your posted code doesn't work, you are missing the final, crucial part of doing a database query: the part where you actually run the query.

```
    $conn = mysql_connect("server", "username", "password") or error_log(mysql_error()); 
    mysql_select_db("database") or error_log(mysql_error());
    $sql = 'UPDATE counters SET Hits =\'0\' WHERE Page = \'$ind_reset\';';
    mysql_query($sql, $conn) or error_log(mysql_error());
```

I hope you have noted that I replaced "die" with "error_log."  If you do error_log(mysql_error(), 1, 'youremail@example.com'), it will email it to you.  Otherwise, as with in my examples, it gets put into wherever your system's error log file is.  You can then have a nice history of your database errors so that, when you inevitably return to StackOverflow with more questions, you can tell us exactly what's been going on. If you use a file, just make sure to either rotate the error log file's name (I name them according to the day's date) or clear it out regularly, or it can get really, really long.

Using the mysqli code you posted in your comment is a better idea than the mysql_* functions, but you don't quite have it correct. The "bind_param" part sticks your variable into the spot where the question mark is.  If your variable is a string, you put "s" first, or if it's an integer, you put "i" first, etc.  And make sure you close things once you're done with them.

```
    $db = new mysqli("server", "username", "password", "database");
    if(!$db->connect_errno) {
        $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE counters SET Hits = '0' where Page = ?");  
        $stmt->bind_param('s',$ind_reset); //assuming $ind_reset is a string
        if(!$stmt->execute()) {
            error_log($stmt->error);
        }
        $stmt->close();
    } else {
        error_log($db->connect_error);
    }
    $db->close();
```

Comment: Thank you very much, spsc_tech, for the explaination. I am always willing to learn what I am doing wrong rather then just have someone correct it! Greatly appreciated!! Have not yet tried it but will do so soon. Just to clearify, there is no user input here it's just me and the button value/name but very good to know for future! Will get back soon!

Comment: after trying a few changes, the only thing that worked is your mysqli code. I'm still studying this to figure out why, but issue resolved! Thanks again!

Comment: You thank me by accepting my answer so I get reputation points. :)  I highly suggest turning on E_ALL error reporting while you are learning so that you see all the errors, then turning it off when you are done.

Comment: ... and I just remembered that mysql_* can't take semicolons, so that's one reason that one would fail.

Comment: Answer accepted and I would upvote but not enough rep. If anyone else can upvote please do, excellent answer and explanation.